# How to style a custom TabItem's Header in a style's trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, tabcontrol, controltemplate

Following [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305740/how-to-style-a-tabcontrols-tabitem-without-styling-their-contentpresenters), I'm left with the following XAML:

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TabItemContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>                                    
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" TargetName="TabItemContent"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>    
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem>
              <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="First"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="Tab"/>
                </StackPanel>
              </TabItem.Header>
              <TextBlock Text="TextBlock"/>                    
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TAB2">
               <TextBlock Text="TextBlock too"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The styling works well for the second tab (which has a simple Header), but doesn't for the first one (with a 'complex' header).

Is there a way to bypass this behavior? I can't think of one myself; I tried replacing the "TextElement" by "TabItem" with no success.

*EDIT: removed irrelevant XAML parts.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a difficult problem; inheritance works by the logical tree, and the logical parent of the complex header is the TabItem. If you set the Foreground on a TabItem, the content of the tabitem will inherit that foreground as well, and that is something that you don't want.

Luckily there is a simple solution: put the UI in a HeaderTemplate instead of the Header property. The root of the template doesn't have a logical parent, but it does have the ContentPresenter as its TemplatedParent, and apparently inheritance also propagates from templated parent to the root in the template.

Comment: That does work, but it clearly doesn't satisfy me. It's hack-ish. And what if I had to use an actual HeaderTemplate in a style?

Comment: What do you mean with 'HeaderTemplate in a style'? But it's true, if you as a control author don't have control over what it is put in the Header/Template, then it's not the best solution. The issue here is that the TabItem is the logical parent for both a complex header and complex content. So another solution would then be to set the Foreground explicitly on the UI in the Content of the TabItem, and to set the Foreground of the TabItem in the trigger.

Comment: Yes, that is most likely the better solution here, until proven otherwise... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with a somewhat elegant solution, even though extremely limited (it will only be usable if your custom headers only are meant to contain 2 text elements, if you want more, this won't work, although it doesn't seem impossible to replace a TextBlock by a Image; but yeah, 2 elements).

I just added a `HeaderTemplate` setter in the TabItem's Style, and do my dark bidings here, binding to Tag to get the name of the tab.

Here's how it goes:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Margin="2,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="2,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="TabItemContent" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabItemContent" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And how it's used (placing the above Style in your Window/UserControl/TabControl's resources):

```
<TabItem Header="{Binding SomeValue}" Tag="TabName">
    <some:Controls/>
</TabItem>
```

Due to the use of a StackPanel, if SomeValue is null, your TabItem will only show "TabName".